# How can I change my default shell without the use of a terminal?

Tags: bash, shell

While trying to change my shell from [Fish](https://fishshell.com/) to [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), I forgot to change my default shell to Bash before uninstalling Fish and exiting the terminal. Because of this, my terminal crashes on launch since it cannot find the shell (Fish) that has been uninstalled. Hence, I am unable to use `chsh`, nor can I invoke the `sudo` permissions I require to manually edit `/etc/passwd`.

For information, I am running Arch Linux, use Alacritty as a terminal emulator, and have Bash installed (although not set as default).

Any solutions to this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.linuxtechi.com/boot-arch-linux-single-user-mode-rescue-mode/

Comment: Do you have the password for the root user? Presumably you didn't change its shell. If so, you should be able to log in as root in a tty. If that doesn't work, and you still have an arch install iso, you can boot into that, mount the drive and edit `/etc/passwd` (either in a chroot or directly from the iso's shell).